# Lambda filter 2 objects deep

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have a lambda expression that needs to filter 2 levels deep. I have a Parent called "Panel", a Panel can contain many "Documents" and I need to return all Panels and their associated documents that have documents of a certain document type...which is passed in as a dropdown list value.

This is what I've got: (I've modified it a little for display purposes)

```
using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var query = ctx.Panels.Where(p => p.blah blah blah).ToList();

    if (DDL.SelectedValue!= string.Empty)
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Documents.Any(d => d.DocumentTypeID ==  DDL.SelectedValue.ToInt32Extension())).ToList();
    }             
    rptPanelReviews.DataSource = query
    rptPanelReviews.DataBind();
}
```

...as you can see, I'm using the `.Any()` method of the Documents object but that returns irrelevant information. The `All()` method returns nothing and I can't find any other method that will return all Panels and Documents that have a specific document Type.

Does anyone know how to go about this? Is it even possible? Can you do this type of query within a Where statement?

Comment: Do you want *only* the documents of the given type (and their parent panels) or do you want *all* documents *as long as any* of them are of the chosen type?

Comment: What *irrelevant information* means?

Comment: Yes I only want documents of their given type and their parent panels. When I say "Irrelevant Information" I mean it is returning documents that are associated to their parent panel but that are not of the specified document type.

Comment: @user1595629 then you should create new Panels (you can't remove documents of unappropriated type with Linq)

Comment: If I can't remove them, Is it possible to only select the ones I need?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like this should get you started?

```
var res = from p in ctx.Panels
          where p.id = blah
          select new
          {
             p.Name,
             Docs = p.Where(d => d.DocumentTypeID ==  DDL.SelectedValue.ToInt32Extension())
          }
```

Comment: Not sure how to implement this. I have a few other filters that I didn't post originally because they weren't relevant but every filter works the same: if (otherDDL.Value != "") query = query.Where(...). Not sure how to change this to Linq while keeping the others using lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems correct (it returns all panels, which have at least one document of required type), but second filtering currently executed in memory. I suggest you to remove `ToList()` till time when you assign query result as data source:

```
using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var query = ctx.Panels.Where(p => p.blah blah blah);

    if (DDL.SelectedValue != String.Empty)
    {
        var docTypeID = DDL.SelectedValue.ToInt32Extension();
        query = query.Where(p => p.Documents.Any(d => d.DocumentTypeID == docTypeID));
    }             

    rptPanelReviews.DataSource = query.ToList();
    rptPanelReviews.DataBind();
}
```

UPDATE: you can't remove documents of unappropriated type with Linq, you can only create new objects with filtered documents

```
if (DDL.SelectedValue != String.Empty)
{
   var docTypeID = DDL.SelectedValue.ToInt32Extension();
   rptPanelReviews.DataSource =
           query.Where(p => p.Documents.Any(d => d.DocumentTypeID == docTypeID))
                .Select(p => {
                    // copy required properties
                    Documents = p.Documents
                                 .Where(d => d.DocumentTypeID == docTypeID)
                                 .ToList()
                }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I've tried removing the ToList until I bind and I get the same result. It does return all Panels with at least one document of required type but it is also returning other documents of other types. I need to only return documents of required type.

Comment: @user1595629 it is impossible, because only documents of required type are added to panels

Comment: This looks pretty good lazyberezovsky...I'm just getting an error under the .ToList() Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProjectName.Model.Document>' to 'System.Data.Objects.Data.Classes.EntityCollection<MyProjectName.Model.Document>'. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1595629 oops, sorry. That was bad idea of creating new `Panel` entities. You should use anonymous type, or some other type instead.